# Компоненты формы не доступны в другой форме

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает, можно ли сделать так, чтобы компоненты одной формы были доступны в другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. В той форме, в которой вам нужен доступ Нажмите "File->Use unit" и выберите нужную форму. После чего компонент будет доступен как <Название формы>.<Название экземпляра>.

Answer (score 2):

А модуль объявил? Uses Form2;

Answer (score 1):

действительно, надо объявить Uses unit2, если форма создана автоматически через команду new form, в модуле unit2 автоматически создалась глобальная переменная Form2 и обращение к компонентам этой формы можно осуществить, например, так Form2.Button1